# Google pubsub client can't subscribe with Locust

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, locust

I'm trying to implement a `GCloudSubUser` for the Python library Locust. I'm implementing this custom User because I need the user to:

- send a message to a topic of Google Pub/sub
- wait for my API's response, which will be sent to an output topic

So far this is what I have:

```py
import os

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from locust import User


class GCloudSubUser(User):
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self, environment) -> None:
        super().__init__(environment)

        self.client = GCloudSubClient(environment)


class GCloudSubClient:
    def __init__(self, environment):
        self.environment = environment

    def publish(self):
        # ...some code to publish to a topic...

        project_id = os.getenv("PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID")
        subscription_id = os.getenv("PUBSUB_TOPIC_ID")

        subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)
        future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
        print("I reached this point")


def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
    print(f"Received {message}.")
    message.ack()
```

The problem I have is that it seems Locust prevents me from subscribing. This line blocks forever and I never see the log message:

```py
future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
```

I'm able to subscribe to the output topic if I don't use Locust, and I can see messages flowing in.
Would you know why this is happening?

Comment: Is the Google pubsub package compatible with gevent? Locust uses gevent for concurrency so everything you run needs to be compatible with that or it won't work. This kind of behavior you're describing is a symptom of incompatibility. You could try to find another package that works or you could try to do something like this to wrap the async code to be gevent compatible. https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/users/playwright.py

Comment: yeah, I suspected that. It took me a while but this comment is the solution: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4629#issuecomment-376962677