How do I make google pubsub work with Locust?
I'm trying to implement a GCloudSubUser for the Python library Locust. I'm implementing this custom User because I need the user to:
send a message to a topic of Google Pub/sub
The issues seems to be in incompability between gRPC and gevent as posted here
Google pubsub client can't subscribe with Locust
and here
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4629#issuecomment-376962677
I tried the steps but cannot get it to work ...any ideas? many thanks!
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import grpc.experimental.gevent as grpc_gevent
grpc_gevent.init_gevent()

import grpc._cython.cygrpc
grpc._cython.cygrpc.init_grpc_gevent()

import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from locust import User, task


class GCloudSubUser(User):
   
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self, environment) -> None:
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.client = GCloudSubClient(environment)

class GCloudSubClient:
    def __init__(self, environment):
        self.environment = environment
    def publish(self):
        print("Very simple client")
    def publish_messages(self):
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        project_id = os.getenv("PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID")
        topic_id = os.getenv("PUBSUB_TOPIC_ID")
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
        for n in range(1, 10):
            data_str = f"Message number {n}"
            data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
            future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
            print(future.result())
        print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}")


Have you looked at this? There's a potential solution in the comments.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76723421/google-pubsub-client-cant-subscribe-with-locust

yes - I looked at that thread - thanks! the error seems to be in this line: print(future.result()) I have removed the line and it is working now
